# Selection sort 'switch' code

Tags: python, sorting

There's a part of the selection sort algorithm that I don't understand. In the latter part of the code (where the `temp` variable is used, why are `L[i]` and `L[minIndx]` assigned values? Aren't those values themselves? Can't only variables be assigned values?

```
def selSort(L):
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        minIndx = i
        minVal = L[i]
        j = i+1
        while j < len(L):
            if minVal > L[j]:
                minIndx = j
                minVal = L[j]
            j += 1
    # aren’t L[i] and L[minIndx] values? How can they be assigned to new values?
        if minIndx != i:
            temp = L[i]
            L[i] = L[minIndx]
            L[minIndx] = temp
```

Comment: tag the language you used for better results

Comment: as a side note, in python you don't need any temp variables to swap two values. `a,b = b,a` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L[0]` for example references a value or reference ... if you have an array `L=[10,20,30]` ... `L[0]` references the value `10` and when you do `L[0]` the result will be the value of the referenced index - `10` ... when you do `L[0] = 100` ... this value for index `0` will be changed to `100`. you can not do `10 = 100` because `10` is a constant value, not a variable, but you can do `L[0] = 100` because `L[0]` references a place in the array.

Comment: Thanks Reflective. That's super helpful. Please let me know what you meant with tag the language you used? Should I have just included more tags to get better question search results? Thanks again for your feedback! I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Reflective. I really appreciate it and will try to add more correct tags in the future. I'm still new to programming and these forums, so your help and explanation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`L` is an array which is a variable that contains a number of indexed elements, each of which is like another variable that can be assigned a new value.

So `L[i]` and `L[minIndx]` are both array elements that can be assigned new values, which is what's being done here to move around the elements to sort them.